# Python string text file with \n separating words will not split

Tags: python, list, split

I was given a long .txt file that when read returns one long string that is a large corpus of words that are separated by \n as shown:

```
\na+\nabound\nabounds\nabundance\nabundant\naccessable\naccessible\nacclaim\nacclaimed\nacclamation\naccolade\naccolades\naccommodative\naccomodative\naccomplish\naccomplished\naccomplishment...\nworld-famous\nworth\nworth-while\nworthiness\nworthwhile\nworthy\nwow\nwowed\nwowing\nwows\nyay\nyouthful\nzeal\nzenith\nzest\nzippy\n
```

I need to split this string into a list of these words but none of the commands I usually use for .csv files is working.  I have tried stripping, replacing(), split(), splitline() and nothing will break this into a list of these words.  I would be grateful for any assistance.

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '[',']','@']
punctuation_chars2=["'", '"', ",", ".", "!",":",";",'#','[',']','@','\n']
    # list of positive words to use
    positive_words = []
    wrd_list = []
    new_list = []
    with open("positive_words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-16") as pos_f:
        for lin in pos_f:
            if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
                positive_words.append(lin.strip())

        pos_wrds = positive_words[0]
        pos_wrds.strip()
        print(pos_wrds)
        for p in punctuation_chars:
            pos_wrds = pos_wrds.replace(p,"")
        print(pos_wrds)


wrd_list = pos_wrds.splitlines()
new_list = wrd_list[-1].splitlines
```

I would like to see a python list with each word separated:
list = [a+, abound, abounds, abundance, abundant...]

Comment: You mean `pos_f.read().split('\n')` doesn't work...?

Comment: `\n` is first char in your text so you can cut it from text - `text[0]` - and use with `split(text[0])`. Maybe it is not the same char as `'\n'`. Some time ago Windows was using `"\r\n"`, Linux was using `"\n"` and Mac was using `"\r"` You could also check code of this char `ord(text[0])` and compare with `ord("\n")`

Comment: `alist = list(open("my_file.txt"))`

Comment: if you see `\n` in text then it is not `"new line"` but normal text `"\\n"` - try `split("\\n")`

Comment: Right: you've tried to split on the `newline` character, but your file apparently contains the individual characters `\\` and 'n'.

Comment: Thank you thank you all!  I really appreciate this guidance.  What worked was split("\\n").  I kept trying to replace it as regular txt with a space but that didn't work.  I have almost exclusively worked with numbers and data for my entire life so working with .txt strings is challenging for me and why I am studying it now.

Answer (score 2):

splitlines works pretty well:

```
In [1]: text = "\na+\nabound\nabounds\nabundance\nabundant\naccessable\naccessible\nacclaim\nacclaimed\nacclamation\naccolade\naccolades\naccommodative\naccomodative\naccomplish\naccomplished\naccomplishment...\nworld-famous\nworth\nw
   ...: orth-while\nworthiness\nworthwhile\nworthy\nwow\nwowed\nwowing\nwows\nyay\nyouthful\nzeal\nzenith\nzest\nzippy\n"                                                                                                                 

In [2]: text.splitlines()                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[2]: 
['',
 'a+',
 'abound',
 'abounds',
 'abundance',
 'abundant',
 'accessable',
 'accessible',
 'acclaim',
 'acclaimed',
 'acclamation',
 'accolade',
 'accolades',
 'accommodative',
 'accomodative',
 'accomplish',
 'accomplished',
 'accomplishment...',
 'world-famous',
 'worth',
 'worth-while',
 'worthiness',
 'worthwhile',
 'worthy',
 'wow',
 'wowed',
 'wowing',
 'wows',
 'yay',
 'youthful',
 'zeal',
 'zenith',
 'zest',
 'zippy']
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is not working for me.  I have tried this in my code and it didn't result in a list like your response above.

Answer (score 0):

string.splitlines() work on the lines of Python text file.

A Python text file is an ordered collection (sequence) of lines.  Each line is a string terminated with "\n".  So using `positive_words.append(lin.split('\\n'))` works because for your file you must escape the backslash character for it to be treated as a backslash and not as a newline "\n" character.

```
'''
print('\na+\nabound\nabounds\nabundance\nabundant\naccessable\naccessible\nacclaim\nacclaimed\nacclamation\naccolade\naccolades\naccommodative\naccomodative\naccomplish\naccomplished\naccomplishment...\nworld-famous\nworth\nworth-while\nworthiness\nworthwhile\nworthy\nwow\nwowed\nwowing\nwows\nyay\nyouthful\nzeal\nzenith\nzest\nzippy\n')
'''

# punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '[',']','@']
# punctuation_chars2=["'", '"', ",", ".", "!",":",";",'#','[',']','@','\n']

# list of positive words to use
positive_words = []
wrd_list = []
new_list = []
with open("positive_words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        positive_words.append(lin.split('\\n'))

    pos_wrds = positive_words[0]

print(pos_wrds)

#    for p in punctuation_chars:
#        pos_wrds = pos_wrds.replace(p,"----")
#    print(pos_wrds)

# wrd_list = pos_wrds.splitlines(0)
# new_list = wrd_list[-1].splitlines()
```

Your last 6 lines need to be modified, because they are using string methods on a list, which is throwing errors.

You need to test for punctuation and non-alphanumeric characters explicitly, because your file has punctuation in one element "accomplishment..." and "a+" in another.

Test each list item separately as a string in the `pos_wrds` list.  Also, your punctuation list has "\n" and "@", which are control characters and special characters (technically not punctuation characters).

If you really need to test for punctuation, then use the Python `string` package to test for characters in the punctuation character set.

See [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) for more information on the String library.   It is awesomely powerful !!

Comment: Rich -  thanks for the guidance on this, that helped and I was able to complete the project!